# Azure Open AI Studio uploading Help Guide for data

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, azure-openai, azure-ai

We're wanting to take our help guide and use that to build training data to upload into Azure Open AI studio (Azure OpenAI Studio -> File Management).

Is there any examples on taking a help/user guide and building data from that which we can feed into azure's openai studio to train the models to use via an azure ai endpoint?

Can find plenty of examples how to do some basic prompt and completion but nothing complex past that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Microsoft's documentation has been the best I've been able to find so far. I've attached their most basic quick start guide, but assuming you're looking to do more than play around with a model, you'll probably want to research the types of data sources you can connect, like Azure Blob storage or SharePoint, and which would make the most sense for you.

Researching indexers and indexes, and how to make them would also probably be beneficial.

Microsoft's documentation has been the most useful to me so far, but hopefully some other resources arrive soon.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/use-your-data-quickstart?tabs=command-line&pivots=rest-api